# pip: No matching distribution found for detectron2

Tags: python, pip, detectron

When I have the following line in `requirements.txt`

```
detectron2 -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu101/index.html
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement detectron2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for detectron2
```

However trying to execute this on the command line, it installs the packages, but I would really prefer everything to be in the requirements.txt

This happens even if the requirements.txt does not have any other entries.

```
pip install detectron2 -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu101/index.html
```

Any idea what is the problem? Is there some other requirement listed in requirements.txt that causes this? How could I find out which one?

This is inside a Docker container based on `python:3.7-slim-buster` which, if I am not mistaken, is based on Debian buster. It is running Python 3.7.11.

I tried this in both a virtualenv and without it.

Other packages from requirements.txt get installed properly.

Comment: What is your OS and python version?

Comment: OS and python version are now added to the post.